# how to make selected item in drop down list redirect to a function in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How am I going to make when i choose my item in my drop down list menu and its redirect to my function ? below is my function
I'm using vb.net and below how my drop down menu list function

this is what my drop down menu do

```
ddlWafer.Items.Clear()

    If txtLot.Text = "A" Then
        ddlWafer.Items.Add("123")
        ddlWafer.Items.Add("456")

        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtLot.Text = "B" Then

        ddlWafer.Items.Add("789")
        ddlWafer.Items.Add("1122")

        Exit Sub
    End If
```

After i choose in drop down menu list for let say "123" I want to execute this function onclick

```
Public Function GetMap()
Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\Downloads\" & txtLot.Text & "." & ddlWafer.SelectedValue & ".txt"    
Dim Line As String = ""
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder
Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(filename)
Line = sr.ReadLine
   Do
       If Line = "#" Then
                Line = sr.ReadLine
                Do
                    sb.AppendLine(Line)
                    Line = sr.ReadLine
                Loop Until Line = "##"
            End If
            Line = sr.ReadLine
        Loop Until Line = ""
        TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: You have an extra `"` at the end of the second line.  Can you edit it out to fix the colors?  On second though, I think the code here that you've implemented is completely unrelated to what you're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a `SelectedIndexChanged` method on the ComboBox you want to call your method.

[SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Within the method, check whether or not the SelectedItem is the one that you want to call your method, and if it is, call the method.

Comment: so i need to call my prefered function inside this >>        Protected Sub ddlWafer_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlWafer.SelectedIndexChanged
      
    End Sub

Comment: Yes.  Put an if statement that check to see if `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` is equal to the item you want to call your method.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I wasn't aware of the difference between combobox and dropdownlist, but `SelectedIndexChanged` will work on both (as well as listboxes).

Comment: If this worked for you, please remember to upvote and accept answer.  If you're still having issues, please update the question with more details.